# Where can I get some real life CDR/SMDR/AMA logs from asterisk or ther IP based switch?

Tags: asterisk, pbx

In order to develop some generic call accounting software I need some sample logs from IP based PBX. Where can I get some? - I need more than 100 records, preferably using both SIP and telephony trunks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading something like [AsteriskNOW](http://www.asterisk.org/asterisknow) and installing it on a VM - it's relatively easy to get going with an IP phone.

The CDR's are stored in mysql for most asterisk installations (although it's not required, just the norm) and the format is relatively similar.

I'm not sure an excerpt of a random system would really allow for particularly robust development - most of the "generic" call logging systems I know of involve exporting CDR's (in whatever format they may be) to a format the generic system can read using csv/xml/etc, as the information available will vary from switch to switch and system to system depending on the type of switch, dialplan/extensions and calling contexts.